# How could one implement clone() method in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, clone

Suppose there is a class `AbstractCollection` that may have many sub-classes, which have similar constructors (accepting entries). Is it possible to implement a `clone()` method in `AbstractCollection`, that would create and return a new instance of actual sub-class, passing in the entries?

```
class AbstractCollection<T> {
  constructor(items: T[]) {
    // ...
  }

  clone(): AbstractCollection<T> {
    // TODO: implement
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure thing, what you're looking for is `this.constructor`:

```
class AbstractCollection<T> {
    private items: T[];

    constructor(items: T[]) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    clone(): AbstractCollection<T> {
        return new (this.constructor as { new(items: T[]): AbstractCollection<T>})(this.items);
    }
}
```

And then:

```
class MyCollection1 extends AbstractCollection<string> {}

class MyCollection2 extends AbstractCollection<number> { }

let a = new MyCollection1(["one", "two", "three"]);
let clonedA = a.clone();
console.log(clonedA); // MyCollection1 {items: ["one", "two", "three"]}

let b = new MyCollection2([1, 2, 3]);
let clonedB = b.clone();
console.log(clonedB); // MyCollection2 {items: [1, 2, 3]}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20AbstractCollection%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20items%3A%20T%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(items%3A%20T%5B%5D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.items%20%3D%20items%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20clone()%3A%20AbstractCollection%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20(this.constructor%20as%20%7B%20new(items%3A%20T%5B%5D)%3A%20AbstractCollection%3CT%3E%7D)(this.items)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MyCollection1%20extends%20AbstractCollection%3Cstring%3E%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MyCollection2%20extends%20AbstractCollection%3Cnumber%3E%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20a%20%3D%20new%20MyCollection1(%5B%22one%22%2C%20%22two%22%2C%20%22three%22%5D)%3B%0D%0Alet%20clonedA%20%3D%20a.clone()%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(clonedA)%3B%20%2F%2F%20MyCollection1%20%7Bitems%3A%20%5B%22one%22%2C%20%22two%22%2C%20%22three%22%5D%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20b%20%3D%20new%20MyCollection2(%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D)%3B%0D%0Alet%20clonedB%20%3D%20b.clone()%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(clonedB)%3B%20%2F%2F%20MyCollection2%20%7Bitems%3A%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%7D))